# Font size too small: 0 error in c# in exporting a content from gridview to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

my code is:

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
  {
  using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
                GridView2.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A2);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();


                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("contentdisposition","attachment;filename=CustomerReport.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
            }
        }*/
```

please help me to resolve this. In this i am getting `font size too small error.Error in htmlparser.parse()`

Comment: So what *is* the HTML you are trying to write?

Comment: its lyk a table with name and  slot alloted from db using gridview

Comment: I can see that. I meant you need to debug. What is the text that sr passes to htmlparser in `Parse` that it chokes on? Is there a font size given? Maybe it actually *is* too small? The error message is crystal clear. You need to find out how you can fix it.

Comment: can u make it clear as what your telling .if size not given it has to take the default bt error is shown in this line"htmlparser.parse(sr);"

Comment: Your parser is trying to parse something. I do not know what it looks like. You don't seem to know what it looks like. As long as we don't know, we cannot find the error. Basic debugging.

Comment: @nvoigt: It shows Font size too small:0 error

Comment: I know what it shows. And it's probably correct. You don't seem to know what you passed in as parameter. I will not post any more until you post the text that is passed as parameter to the `Parse` method.